# smallest subset of array whose sum is equal to key. Condition : Values can be used any number of times

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was asked this question in interview.
Given a list of 'N' coins, their values being in an array A[], return the minimum number of coins required to sum to 'S' (you can use as many coins you want). If it's not possible to sum to 'S', return -1 
Note here i can use same coins multiple times.

Example:

Input #00:

Coin denominations: { 1,3,5 }

Required sum (S): 11

Output #00:

3

Explanation: 
The minimum number of coins requires is: 3 - 5 + 5 + 1 = 11;

Is there any better way we can think except `Sorting the array and start it by both ends`?

Comment: I don't see a better approach than dynamic programming, which is basically cached recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

A simple greedy approach, which you seem to be thinking of, won't always produce an optimal result. If you elaborate a bit on what exactly you mean by starting from both ends, I might be able to come up with a counter-example.

It has a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach, taken from [here](http://learn.hackerearth.com/tutorial/dynamic-programming/23/change-making-problem/):

> Let `C[m]` be the minimum number of coins of denominations `d1`,`d2`,...,`dk` needed to make change for `m` amount. In the optimal solution to making change for `m` amount, there must exist some first coin `di`, where `di < m`. Furthermore, the remaining coins in the solution must themselves be the optimal solution to making change for `m - di`.
>
> Thus, if `di` is the first coin in the optimal solution to making change for `m` amount, then `C[m] = 1 + C[m - di]`, i.e. one `di` coin plus `C[m - di]` coins to optimally make change for `m - di` amount. We don't know which coin `di` is the first coin; however, we may check all `n` such possibilities (subject to the constraint that `di < m`), and the value of the optimal solution must correspond to the minimum value of `1 + C[m - di]`, by definition.
>
> Furthermore, when making change for 0, the value of the optimal solution is clearly 0 coins. We thus have the following recurrence.
>
> ```
> C[p] = 0                                if p = 0
>        min(i: di < p) {1 + C[p - di]}   if p > 0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Pathfinding algorithms (Dijkstra, A*, meeting on the middle, etc.) could be suitable for this on graph like this:

```
                  0
                1/|\5
                / |3\
               /  |  \
             1    3    5
           1/|\51/|  ...
           / |3\/ |3
          /  | /\ |
         2   4    6
          ....
```

Other way is recursive bisection. Say, if we cannot get the sum S with one coin, we start to try to get amounts (S/2, S/2)...(S-1,1) recursively until we find suitable coin or reach S=1.

Comment: What's "meeting on the middle"?

Comment: Meet in the middle (sorry did not name it correctly) is a sort of searching algorithms where path is searched simultaneously from start and the finish until two these are meet in some point.